# Playing tag with infinitely many friends

Tags: brownian-motion, differential-games, continuous-geometry

All the countably infinitely many guests of [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) decide to spend the day playing tag in the park. One player is the *runner*, and all the others are it. The taggers can agree on a strategy beforehand, and can communicate and coordinate instantanteously and continuously while the game is played. The runner runs at speed $v_r$, the other players all run at speed $v_{\text{it}}$. The players are allowed to make sharp turns (i.e., their trajectory is not necessarily continuously differentiable); they may even engage in (non-random) Brownian motion.

**Question.** Can the runner avoid the others players indefinitely, if the park is a connected open set $P\subseteq \mathbb R^2$, with finite area and circumference?

I suspect that it is necessary that $v_r>v_{\text{it}}$, because otherwise a single player can catch up with the runner. (To be precise, if $v_r<v_{\text{it}}$ then a player will simply gradually catch up with the runner by running straight towards her; otherwise, if $v_r=v_{\text{it}}$, we use the fact that the park has finite circumference, so the runner will have to make sharp turns infinitely many times, and this is when the player gains on the runner).

---

Some observations:

1. The runner loses to uncountably many taggers, who can close in on her by forming a closed loop
2. The runner wins against one tagger, around whom she runs circles
3. The runner wins against finitely many taggers: she "dodges" her adversaries one by one with maneuvers which she can make arbitrarily small

Answer (score 1):

As you said if $v_r < v_{it}$ the its can trivially catch the runner in finite time, as you already said. But then the situation is somewhat problematic. Consider this: Having countably many catchers means that it is possible to place a catcher onto each spot of a countable dense subset of the area.

Arguably now the runner would have a hard time escaping, because no matter where he moves, there is already a catcher arbitrarily much closer to him. But on the other hand he cannot get caught, as no matter where the runners are placed there will always be plenty more points arbitrarily close than the runners could populate.

No need to speak, in such a situation *speed* does not really make any sense anymore. And the answer depends on you model.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! Even if the runner is faster, the its can coordinate to distribute as $[0,1]^2\cap\mathbb Q^2$, for example. Then there is no closest tagger.  Still, since I allow the runner to move with fractally complex motion, it seems she should still be able to outsmart the taggers. For example, there must be a straight line intersecting the runner on which there is no tagger, so it seems that the runner could move in that direction... You say that the answer depends on my model. What is an example of a model that would make the question well-defined and interesting?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Well, suppose each runner has a catching radius. Then obviously even sufficiently many but finite runners can cover the area. On the other hand if we say a catch counts only of the runner is at the same mathematical point as the it then we need to think about what kind of restriction we’d put on the movement.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm tempted to say that the position $p_t$ at time $t$ must be defined at every point $t\geq 0$, and it must hold that $|p_{t+\delta}-p_t|\leq \delta v$ for every $\delta\geq 0$. Is the question then well-defined, at least in the sense that it now has a yes/no answer? Or do we need more restrictions?

Comment: (1/2) I see. I think this is much more near an answer than where I was just a few minute ago. I think it is slightly more complicated for the runner, though, because the taggers may choose their strategy depending on where the runner goes. So we cannot a priori choose where the runner will be at discrete times, since we may end up colliding with a tagger.

Comment: (2/2) Here is something that's unclear to me. In a game, we usually ask whether there is a move for Alice such that for all Bob's moves, there is a move for Alice such that, etc. So we get an alternation of $\exists,\forall$ quantifiers. This works well when the players take turns; however, here we have a "continuous" number of logical $\exists,\forall$ quantifiers. This issue may be surmountable, but we need to define it properly before the question is well-defined, I think.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Let’s have a look under $|X(t)-X(t_0)| < c|t-t_0|$ (Lipschitz). WLOG assume $t_0=0$. Enumerate the Interval $\mathbb R_+$ by $r_\alpha$ using the well ordering theorem. Suppose for all $\beta < \alpha$ we have defined $X(t_\beta)$ such that the Lipschitz condition holds. Consider the Balls with radius $c|t_\alpha - t_\beta|$ around $X(t_\beta)$. From the Lipschitz condition and the triangular equation I think we should get that these Balls must have a nonempty intersection. This intersection contains uncountably many points.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Thus we can set $X(t_\alpha)$ to one such point and get a situation where the Lipschitz condition holds true for $\beta\leq \alpha$. By doing transfinite recursion (starting with suitable $X(0)$) we can thus define a path, no matter how the runners move.